# Problem with anime hair specular

Tags: hair

I have a mesh of hair. I add a hair material to it, but instead of the reflections being a line, they bounce all over the mesh.

What's the problem? I would like to know what is causing this behavior and is there a way to fix it?

I used: https://gloriatheanimator.gumroad.com/l/QhzwB

Everything looks good on the preview, but on the mesh itself, these speculars do not want to stay at the same height.
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Like exactly what material? We don't know anything about it. Please provide more details by using the edit option under the question.

Comment: Suggest you ask the author of the shader since she's provided links to contact her on the web page at the end of the comments!